# How to add post vars to jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery

I have a form that is submitted via ajax and I need to add post var to execute the task

```
run=update
```

but for some reason the form works only if I change url to

```
update.php?run=update
```

I also tried

```
data:{'run':'update')
```

but it does not work.

this is the ajax request.

```
  var sendForm= $('#sendform');
    sendForm.submit(function(e)
    {

        var formObj = $(this);
        var formURL = 'update.php';
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        $.ajax({
        url: formURL,
        type: 'post',
            data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
            mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

                    console.log(data.message);


            },
             error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

                    console.log(data.error);

             }          
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    sendForm.submit();
```

any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you'll need to add the additional data to the formData object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
data: formData,
```

with

```
data: $.extend(formData, {run: 'update'}),
```

Answer (score 0):

Thnkx to Kevin B pointing out I was missing

```
formData.append( 'run', 'update');
```

so the code that works wold be

```
  var sendForm= $('#sendform');
    sendForm.submit(function(e)
    {

        var formObj = $(this);
        var formURL = 'update.php';
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        formData.append( 'run', 'update');
        $.ajax({
        url: formURL,
        type: 'post',
            data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
            mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

                    console.log(data.message);


            },
             error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

                    console.log(data.error);

             }          
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    sendForm.submit();
```